# Wordpress page error: Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a Wordpress site that I'm developing locally - I am trying to create a new page with the permalink `/jobs`, however when I then try and preview the page I get the following error messages in the browser:

```
Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admiral_wp/wp-content/themes/fanatic/archive.php on line 6

Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admiral_wp/wp-content/themes/fanatic/archive.php on line 6
```

The `archive.php` can be seen in its entirety below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- +++archive -->
<main>
  <?php get_template_part( 'partials/partial' ); ?>
  <?php // Use include if variables need to be passed on to partial ?>
  <?php include(locate_template('partials/partial')); ?>

</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If I change the permalink to anything else (e.g. `jobss`), it works fine and the page renders as expected, so the issue seems to be related specifically to the `/jobs` path. I thought that perhaps it was a reserved word, but there are no custom post types registered as `jobs` - although there is one called `admiral_jobs` which previously had a rewrite in its args, however this has now been removed (`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'jobs')`) and I'm still getting the same error messages.

Any ideas on what else could be causing this error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to `Settings` -> `Permalinks` and hit `Save Changes` button may resolve your issue.